# Import CSV file via PSQL With Array Values

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I have a very simple table where I would like to insert data from a CSV into it.

```
create table products(
  id integer primary key,
  images text[]
);
```

Here is what I am currently trying with my csv:

```
1,"['hello.jpg', 'world.jpg']"
2,"['hola.jpg', 'mundo.jpg']"
```

When I do the following, I get a syntax error from psql, with no additional information what could have gone wrong.

`\copy products 'C:\Users\z\Downloads\MOCK_DATA.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',';`

Does anyone know how to format my array values properly?

Comment: Could you please share the error message?

Comment: All it says is "Syntax error" lol. Nothing else

Comment: 'All it says is "Syntax error" lol. Nothing else'.  Never seen that happen.  Sounds like you client throws away the detailed error message.  What is your client program?  You say psql, but again I've never seen that. Maybe throw the client away.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the square brackets from the `csv` file then I would have the table like this (`images` as `text` rather than `text[]`):

```sql
create table products_raw
(
  id integer primary key,
  images text
);
```

plus this view

```sql
create view products as 
  select id, ('{'||images||'}')::text[] as images 
  from products_raw;
```

and use the view henceforth. Anyway I would rather have the CSV file like this, no formatting, just data:

```
1,"hello.jpg,world.jpg"
2,"hola.jpg,mundo.jpg"
```

It is also worth considering to attach the csv file as a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) using [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html). It is a bit more complicated but usually pays off with several benefits.